# OutGoing Emails in QA wil they send an email to a Live Prod Account

Tags: sharepoint-server, outgoing-email

I have 2 environments QA, PROD and the outgoing emails are setup as below
QA(`sharepointadmin@abc.qa`) and PROD as (`sharepointadmin@abc.com`).
For Ex-I have a simple InfoPath form in QA which takes my first name, Lastname as input and I hit submit and it is supposed to send out an email saying a new item is submitted, but I am not getting any email from QA.

The same scenario works well in PROD so not sure what's wrong here, does QA outgoing talks to PROD.

User Profile Sync Connection has the same ForestName used for QA and PROD 
Forest Name - abc.com

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things can cause the issue:

- In order to send the email, You have to configure the OUT-going email settings.You can compare both QA and Prod from doing thing. Go to `Central Admin> System Settings > Outgoing EMail Settings` Compare both farm's setting.
- Also make sure You sharePoint servers are in email Realy of exchange or SMTP.
  [Configure outgoing email for a SharePoint 2013 farm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)